# Is select faster than insert

Tags: mysql, database, time-complexity

I have an big load file that I downloaded. This contains records that I will have to load into the database. Based on the size of the data, it will likely take 2 weeks or more to finish (since there is preprocessing etc). A coworker asked me to make what she called a delta file, which checks the current database to see if the data already exists based on a certain field in the database and IFF it exists then we will keep that in the load file, otherwise we will discard it.

I'm confused because to implement this I would need to do a select query for every file in the load file to check if it exists. a select would take O(n) I'm assuming. Then the insert (for a smaller data set) an additional O(1).

whereas an insert would just take O(1).

I'd like to 1) understand why this implementation is faster (If I don't understand things properly) and 2) a possible solution to implementation of this delta file if you can think of something smarter than what I suggested

Thanks

Comment: a 2 week import? can you take advantage of unique key(s) and `INSERT IGNORE`? The implementation could be faster or slower for a lot of reasons. Updating indexes, triggers, etc. Hard to say. Create a test with a small subset of data (10 seconds or so) and play around until you find the most efficient.

Comment: @mike B The program running the file that does the fetching, preprocessing inserting etc takes about 5 days, and we're expecting a huge file of approximately 10M records to come in.

Comment: How much time is inserting and how much is processing? There is no way it takes 5 days to insert 10M records in any modern database, even without any optimizations. Five hours would be slow for that. If 99% of the time spent on the import is in processing - which seems virtually guaranteed - then yes, spending time up-front to figure out what records don't need processing is really, really smart. Basically, the time isn't in the insertion OR the select, it's somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Databases make indexes for columns specified in the schema. The way your data is indexed can make a massive difference in performance. Without an index, a select operation may be O(n) but with an index it may be O(1).

Insert operations must maintain the index. For large data loading operations you may be well off to disable indexing until the end so you are doing a single index update on all the data instead of many index updates on each record you insert.

Some measurements I did the other day indicate that selects are faster than inserts in my situation. I came across this question because I am trying to learn if this is generally true or reflects something specific about the way I have it setup.